# Sri Ananta Padmanabha Swami at Thiru-Ananta-Puram (Trivendrum)

Tags: ranganatha

This question is about Sri Ananatha Padmanabha Swami in the reclining pose at Thiru-Ananta-Puram (also known as Trivendrum in the modern times).

My specific question is, The Lord, Sri Ananta Padmanabha Swami is in reclining pose, like Sri Ranganathar at Sri Rangam, but with Sridevi and also a Shiva Lingam right below the Lord's hands pointing down.

What is the exact context behind this? Are there any Puranic stories that expand on this pose? What is the story / concept behind the The Lord Shiva being present as a Shiva Lingam right in front of Lord Sri Ananta Padmanabha Swami?

Also what is the difference in Vaishanvite theology between the poses of Lord Sri Ranganatha and Sri Ananta Padmanabha Swami? Are there any interpretations provided by either Azwars or Vaishnavacharyas?

Thanks in advance for any comprehensive response with references and pointers.

Comment: For what it is worth, the deity at that temple is not the original deity.  http://www.holydham.com/the-temple-the-deity/     **The original Deity made of Iluppa wood was replaced with a new one in the year 1729 AD because a mystical fire in the temple damaged the original Deity. The new Deity (as per the revelation in the priest’s dream) is made up of 12,008 Saligrams.**

Comment: Thank you @yAdRcchika .. You provided a link for which I thank you. But since people turned _"information age"_ into _"misinformation age"_ by creating all kinds of websites, postings, and blogs, it is hard to ascertain what is true and what is not on the Internet. It is very easy to create a website of that kind and publish a story. That website does not cite any references to backup this story. Would have been helpful if that page cited some source / references.

Comment: This link also says the same. This is quoted in wiki article about the temple. http://spst.in/temple-history/    **In 1730 the idol was again moved to ‘Balalaya’ prior to the renovation and reconstruction of the sanctum sanctorum. It took two years for completion. The old wooden idol was replaced by the one that we see today.**  If better references are required, temple records or books quoting them would be the right place.